# RxJS Subject conditional next() update, based on current-new value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular application that stores some data in a Subject

```
dataSubject = new Subject<SomeDataType>();
```

I have two different ways that the data gets updated from the server which look like

```
connection1.on('messageReceived', (newData: SomeDataType) => this.dataService.dataSubject.next(newData))
```

```
connection2.on('messageReceived', (newData: SomeDataType) => this.dataService.dataSubject.next(newData))
```

The problem is that the newData that arrives last, is not necessarily the **latest**.
Each data object contains a timestamp that I want to use.

Is there a way to make the Subject only accept values that have newData.timestamp > currentData.timestamp? Something like a conditional next()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sounds like a case for the `scan` operator:

```
latestData$ = this.dataSubject.pipe(
  // scan will give you the last emitted value and the current value coming through
  // so you can compare them and select which to emit
  scan((last, current) => {
    if (last.timestamp > current.timestamp) {
      return last
    }
    return current;
  }),
  // optional operator to prevent emitting the same value twice 
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

`latestData$` will only emit values when the timestamp is greater than the previous emitted value with this set up.

Comment: what is the reason for checking whether `current` is defined

Comment: first value through, current will be undefined, as there was no previous emission, adn we didn't define a seed parameter

Comment: @bryan60 I think there is no need for that. If the seed parameter is [not provided](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/scan.ts#L94), it will immediately send the value as a `next` notification, instead of calling the provided function.

Comment: seems it's not needed after all.  weird design decision, as scan often (usually?) changes the shape of the emission in practice, and a hidden, hard dependency on a seed value if changing the shape seems suspect. I've always assumed / expected it to mirror the behavior of array `reduce`